# How to create screenplay pattern project with typescript,serenity and cucumber?

Tags: typescript, protractor, serenity-bdd, serenity-js

I want to create a automation framework using screenplay pattern using protractor,serenity,typescript.

I don't know how to create screenplay project with serenity.

Comment: what is mean "screenplay"? You wanna make screenshot on ... ?

Comment: @Oleksii : Screenplay is patter as we have Page Object Model (POM)

Comment: There is a [template library project with exactly this](https://github.com/serenity-js/serenity-js-cucumber-protractor-template). So go there and click the *Use this template* button, You can also check a [working sample](http://working%20sample), https://github.com/serenity-js/todomvc-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Following Steps To Create Project   :**

1. Download and install Node.js
2. install typescript- npm install -g typescript
3. Download and install VS Code.
4. Create a dir - "**project-name**".
5. open command prompt in administrator mode and navigate to created dir path.
6. execute "npm init" command and provides required details such as :

   ```
   A. package name : Name_of_project
   B. version : 1.0.0
   C. description : serenity-js screenplay with protractor project
   D. entry point : index.js
   E. test command : protractor protractor.conf.js
   F. git repository : git repository url
   E. keywords: press enter for nothing
   F. author : Pritam Maske
   G. license : press enter for "ISC"
   H. It will ask for confirmation, press enter if everything looks fine
   I. Above steps will result in package.json file in your project root directory
   ```
7. execute npm install serenity-js serenity-cli typescript ts-node protractor@ @types/node --save-dev
8. execute npm install cucumber@1.x @types/cucumber --save-dev
9. execute npm install chai chai-as-promised chai-smoothie @types/chai @types/chai-as-promised --save-dev
10. Create **Protractor.conf.js** file
11. Create "**tsconfig.json**"
12. Create **feature** directory and add features files
13. Create **step_defination** directory and add step_defination files
14. Create **screenplay** directory with **components**,**tasks** sub-directory inside it
15. Add "**.gitignore**" file  with "target directory" entry inside it

Answer (score 3):

Maybe start with the documentation?
https://serenity-js.org/design/screenplay-pattern.html

Comment: I have already gone through the documentation and didn't found my answer so that's why I have posted this question .... Anyway thanks ..!!!!